# Post image from local machine to facebook user wall

Tags: facebook, image

I am trying to post an image through graph api to the wall of a user.
I tried to post an image hosted in my server and it worked fine. But when I try to post a local file it gives the following error.
Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) picture URL is not properly formatted.

My code is shown below

```
require_once "facebook-sdk/src/facebook.php";

$app_id = "23432423432";
$app_secret = "345345353553535353534534";

// Init facebook api.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true
));
$urlTitle = 'my url';
$review = 'test desc';
//$picLocal = 'http://l.yimg.com/a/i/ww/met/yahoo_logo_in_061509.png';
$picLocal = '@' . realpath('/var/www/PixShare/a.jpg');
$attachment = array('message' => ' testing',
'description' => 'Review: ' . $review,
'access_token' => 'USER ACCESS TOKEN',
'picture' => $picLocal
);
if(!($sendMessage = $facebook->api('/me/feed/','post',$attachment))){
$errors= error_get_last();
echo "Facebook publish error: ".$errors['type'];
echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];
```

Please let me know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook API (or any online app/site) can not retrieve your local files. So you have to host your files online in some way.

Or if you have Static IP, you can open your localhost to internet. And give file destination by your IP. But it is not a good solution, because you have to be connected all the time to internet, and apache running without any errors. And also your internet connection should be great..

So lets host somewhere :)

Comment: You could also just upload the photo as a multipart form instead of trying to link to its URL

Comment: Do you mean passing $_FILE['tmp_name'] in 'picture' => $_FILE['tmp_name'] Could you please explain a bit.

Comment: I tried using a file upload form and set 'picture' => $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] 
Also tried 'source' => $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]
still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
$photo = realpath("mypic.png");
```

and then use this

```
$picLocal = '@' . $photo;
```

if the pic is next to your .php file